# delete cat from my dashbord

Tags: php, html, laravel

i want to delete my list cat here my code

```
<div class="button">
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>catcontroller/anydestroy" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
```

my controller

```
public function anyDestroy($id)
{
    $cats::find($id)->delete();
    DB::table('role_user')->where('user_id',$id)->delete();
    return redirect()->route('users.index')->with('success','User deleted successfully');
}
```

Comment: Java tag should be removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you haven't passed the id of the entity you wish to delete:

ex: `catcontroller/anydestroy/3`

For simplicity try to do the following:

1. Make an `alias` for your route in `routes/web.php`

   `Route::any(‘/catcontroller/anydestroy/{id}’, ['as' => ‘delete_user','uses'=>’UserController@anyDestroy’]);`
2. In your template then you can render the route (Blade):

   `{{ route(‘delete_user', array(‘id'=>$user->id)) }}`

P.S: You should use the `DELETE` method rather than `GET`.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have pass id with href..

You need to pass id with href

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>catcontroller/anydestroy/id" class="btn btn-danger">
              Delete
         </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass $id from the view first. The problem is here

```
 $cats::find($id)->delete();
```

There is the model name define here not the '$cats'no need to second line if you use model name here so remove this line below

```
 DB::table('role_user')->where('user_id',$id)->delete();
```